# Equal Operator Using Index But In Operator Not Using

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with one timestamp type column and one numeric column that has combined index

```
table leads
(
DISPLAY_ID numeric(10),
REC_DATE timestamp without time zone,
SUP_ID numeric(10),
DISTANCE  numeric(10),
RELAX_FLAG numeric(10)
)
"sampletable_indx1" btree ( date(REC_DATE), SUP_ID )
```

when I am running a query with equal ( = ) operator on both the columns, it is running fine

Sample Query 1

```
    SELECT
COUNT(SUP_ID) COUNT,
SUM(CASE WHEN DISTANCE BETWEEN 0 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CNT_50
FROM
(
SELECT
DISPLAY_ID,SUP_ID, DISTANCE
FROM
LEADS
WHERE
date(REC_DATE)=date(now())
AND SUP_ID = 30628898
AND RELAX_FLAG IN (6,7)
)a;
```

```
                                                               QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2.80..2.81 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using sampletable_indx1 on LEADS (cost=0.57..2.79 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((date(REC_DATE) = date(now())) AND (SUP_ID= '30628898'::numeric))
         Filter: (RELAX_FLAG = ANY ('{6,7}'::numeric[]))
 Planning time: 0.213 ms
 Execution time: 0.070 ms
```

But when I run it for In operator for one of the column, it doesn't use the index properly

Sample Query 2

```
    SELECT
COUNT(SUP_ID) COUNT,
SUM(CASE WHEN DISTANCE BETWEEN 0 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CNT_50
FROM
(
SELECT
DISPLAY_ID,SUP_ID, DISTANCE
FROM
LEADS
WHERE
date(REC_DATE)=date(now())
AND SUP_ID IN (30628898, 23767294,  2888493, 58887272, 16226505,  1726042, 39068344, 10544691,  1445776, 24007105)
AND RELAX_FLAG IN (6,7)
)a;
```

```
                                                                QUERY PLAN

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=2.81..2.82 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=1065.310..1065.311 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using sampletable_indx1 on LEADS (cost=0.57..2.80 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=88.814..1065.259 rows=11 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (date(REC_DATE) = date(now()))
         Filter: ((RELAX_FLAG = ANY ('{6,7}'::numeric[])) AND ( SUP_ID = ANY ('{30628898, 23767294,  2888493, 58887272, 16226505,  1726042, 39068344, 10544691,  1445776, 24007105}'::numeric[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 680096
 Planning time: 0.299 ms
 Execution time: 1065.357 ms
```

What could be the reason for the same and how can it be solved ?

Comment: Hmm. The execution plans don't seem to match the queries. Where does that `Aggregate` come from?

Comment: There was also a join in Main query which I have removed while changing the original query to a sample one to post here.

Comment: @alex-k, Thanks for editing.

Comment: Please post the queries and execution plans exactly as you ran them, without editing (other than maybe changing names if you need to). Sometimes something that seems like an insignificant detail isn't.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Edited as suggested.